# Importing cplex linear program file into python

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

I have written my linear program using cplex IBM studio to .mod file as follows:

```
int I = ...;
int J = ...;
int ds[1..I]=...;
int maxnint[1..J]=...;
dvar int E[1..I][1..J][1..6];
dvar boolean V[1..I];
minimize sum(i in 1..I)(E[i,J,maxnint[J]]-ds[i]*V[i]);

subject to{
forall(i in 1..I, j in 1..J, mu in 1..maxnint[j]) E[i,j,mu]>=0;
forall(i in 1..I)( t_max*V[i]     >=E[i,J,maxnint[J]]-ds[i]);
forall(i in 1..I)(-t_max*(1-V[i]) <=E[i,J,maxnint[J]]-ds[i]);
}
```

I want to import this file into python and solve it using the data I read in python.
The data should be something like :

```
import numpy as np
I = range(10)
J = range(6)
ra = np.array([240, 400, 264, 390, 200, 440])
maxnint = np.array([1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4])
ds = np.array([14, 19, 16, 21, 28,
               14, 21, 19, 15, 14
               ])
```

Is it anyway possible? I try to avoid to write constraints in python because I have many constraints and many indexes that should be harder to implement in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use doopl. Small example https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoocallopl.py

```
from doopl.factory import *
# Data
Buses=[
        (40,500),
        (30,400)
        ]

# Create an OPL model from a .mod file
with create_opl_model(model="zootupleset.mod") as opl:
    # tuple can be a list of tuples, a pandas dataframe...
    opl.set_input("buses", Buses)

    # Generate the problem and solve it.
    opl.run()

    # Get the names of post processing tables
    print("Table names are: "+ str(opl.output_table_names))

    # Get all the post processing tables as dataframes.
    for name, table in iteritems(opl.report):
        print("Table : " + name)
    for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
            print(t)

    # nicer display
    for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
        print(t[0]," buses ",t[1], "seats")
```

or if you do not want to use doopl you can call oplrun from python as can be seen at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/callexternalprogram.mod

See also

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooimportoplmodelandaddpythonobjectiveandconstraint.py